# Linq to SQL - Ordenação dinâmica por índice de coluna

Tags: .net, linq, jquery-datatables, order-by, linq-to-sql

Estou usando um componente chamado datatables.js (https://www.datatables.net/) para exibir minhas tabelas e ele possui a propriedade **ServerSide**, que eu chamo, em Ajax, a minha lista de algum lugar. Ele envia a ordenação, sentido por parâmetros. Ele envia o **Índice** da coluna a ser ordenada.
Minha query está assim:

```
var test1 = (from x in Context.MyTable
    where (x.codigo_empresa == User.EnterpriseId
        && (filtro.DataInicial == DateTime.MinValue || x.Vencimento >= filtro.DataInicial)
        && (filtro.DataFinal == DateTime.MinValue || x.Vencimento <= filtro.DataFinal)            
        && (filtro.Status == 0 || x.Status == filtro.Status))
    select (new
    {
        Status = (EnumContas.Status)x.Status,
        Vencimento = x.Vencimento ?? DateTime.MinValue,                                  
        Valor = x.Valor,                 
        id = x.Id,
        IdConta = x.IdConta
    }));
```

Preciso ordená-la de acordo com o índice da coluna que vier por parâmetros (supondo que meu select está na ordem em que serão exibidas as colunas).

Alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o [PredicateBuilder](https://github.com/jrgcubano/predicatebuilder), mais especificamente o [OrderHelper](https://github.com/jrgcubano/predicatebuilder/blob/master/PredicateBuilder/Helpers/OrderHelper.cs).

Fazer algo como:

```
var ordenado = OrderHelper.GetOrderedQueryable<Entidade>(query, orders);
```

Onde `orders` é um array [OrderInfo](https://github.com/jrgcubano/predicatebuilder/blob/master/PredicateBuilder/Base/OrderInfo.cs) que você pode construir de forma dinâmica.

Tem um exemplo [aqui](https://github.com/jrgcubano/predicatebuilder/blob/master/PredicateBuilder/Services/StudentService.cs) também.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Não utilizei exatamente o código que me mandaste, mas ele me ajudou muito em como fazer.